# Query is too Complex? Using an append query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, append, ms-access-2010

I have been using this append query for days and it randomly throws this exception:

> Query is too Complex

The query inserts into a different table the data retrieved back from a union query.

```
INSERT INTO [CA-SSI Dispatch]
SELECT 
SSIQuery.[Phonenumber] AS Phonenumber, 
SSIQuery.[FormRecordNumber] AS FormRecordNumber, 
SSIQuery.[InspectedBY] AS InspectedBY, 
SSIQuery.[Project] AS Project, 
SSIQuery.[DateTimeInspection] AS DateTimeInspection, 
SSIQuery.[Question] AS Question, 
SSIQuery.[Answer] AS Answer, 
SSIQuery.[Rank] AS Rank, 
SSIQuery.[Comment] AS Comment, 
SSIQuery.[Regulation] AS Regulation
FROM SSIQuery

WHERE NOT EXISTS    
(SELECT *    FROM [CA-SSI Dispatch]    WHERE   SSIQuery.[Phonenumber] = [CA-SSI Dispatch].[Phonenumber]    
AND   SSIQuery.[FormRecordNumber] =[CA-SSI Dispatch].[FormRecordNumber]    
AND   SSIQuery.[Project] = [CA-SSI Dispatch].[Project]   
AND   SSIQuery.[DateTimeInspection] = [CA-SSI Dispatch].[DateTimeInspection] 
AND SSIQuery.[Question] = [CA-SSI Dispatch].[Question] 
AND SSIQuery.[Answer] = [CA-SSI Dispatch].[Answer]
AND SSIQuery.[FormRecordNumber] = [CA-SSI Dispatch].[FormRecordNumber]);
```

The INSERT INTO stopped working and kept returning that error after I added more fields to my union query.  If it helps this is part of my union query. This UNION QUERY, continues to work.

```
SELECT
SSIAns.phonenumber AS Phonenumber,
SSIAns.Form_Record_Number As FormRecordNumber,
SSIAns.Inspected_By AS InspectedBY,
SSIAns.Project,
SSIAns.Date_Time_of_Inspection AS DateTimeInspection,
QR.q1 AS Question,
SSIAns.Clean_level_ground AS Answer,
SSIRank.Rank_1 AS Rank,
SSIComment.Comment_1 AS Comment,
QR.r1 AS Regulation

FROM SSIAns, SSIRank,SSIComment, QR

WHERE 
SSIRank.Rank_1 = "2_Address_Within_3_Days" AND 
SSIAns.Form_Record_Number=SSIRank.Form_Record_Number 
AND SSIRank.Form_Record_Number =SSIComment.Form_Record_Number

UNION 
SELECT
SSIAns.phonenumber AS Phonenumber,
SSIAns.Form_Record_Number As FormRecordNumber,
SSIAns.Inspected_By AS InspectedBY,
SSIAns.Project,
SSIAns.Date_Time_of_Inspection AS DateTimeInspection,
QR.q2 AS Question,
SSIAns.Adequate_ramps_barricading AS Answer,
SSIRank.Rank_2 AS Rank,
SSIComment.Comment_2 AS Comment,
QR.r1 AS Regulation

FROM SSIAns, SSIRank,SSIComment, QR

WHERE 
SSIRank.Rank_2 = "2_Address_Within_3_Days" AND 
SSIAns.Form_Record_Number=SSIRank.Form_Record_Number 
AND SSIRank.Form_Record_Number =SSIComment.Form_Record_Number
```

The union query goes on over and over with the next corresponding fields. Ex: rank_3, rank_4 etc

Both queries were working fine until I added up til the 50th

```
UNION 
SELECT
SSIAns.phonenumber AS Phonenumber,
SSIAns.Form_Record_Number As FormRecordNumber,
SSIAns.Inspected_By AS InspectedBY,
SSIAns.Project,
SSIAns.Date_Time_of_Inspection AS DateTimeInspection,
QR.q2 AS Question,
SSIAns.Adequate_ramps_barricading AS Answer,
SSIRank.Rank_50 AS Rank,
SSIComment.Comment_50 AS Comment,
QR.r1 AS Regulation

FROM SSIAns, SSIRank,SSIComment, QR

WHERE 
SSIRank.Rank_50 = "2_Address_Within_3_Days" AND 
SSIAns.Form_Record_Number=SSIRank.Form_Record_Number 
AND SSIRank.Form_Record_Number =SSIComment.Form_Record_Number
```

Now, only the union query works, when I try to run the INSERT INTO query, to insert into a secondary table, I run the error "Query is too Complex"
With the union query, we're trying to break down the question to corresponding answer, rank & comment, into one record. So question 1 & corresponding fields is one record. Question 2 & corresponding fields is a different record.

Comment: If you're doing essentially the same query 50 times you quite obviously have a schema problem.

Comment: I defiinitely know you're right on that one. We're kinda stuck, because we're using a third party program that writes into an access table a record across for all 97 questions, each question correlating with rank, comment, answer. Now, we have to break down each individual question with its correlating fields, into one record and besides using this query, I'm not quite sure how else to split up these records it writes.

Comment: If you can't change the table and the table design is broken, can you do a one-time normalisation of the data, perhaps by trigger or scheduled job, to copy the data into a schema that is easier to work with? That task would be relatively simple, save your sanity and allow you to create other reports too

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you added the table QR to your queries but didnt join it to anything which is likely causing the error.

In the were clause you need to make a QR table field equal to another table to have it join together and pull into the query.

This is all secondary to first and foremost standardizing your code to using joins and not the approach of "FROM table1,table2,table3)"

Instead you want to do:
    FROM Table1
    INNER JOIN TABLE2
    ON table1.column1 = TABLE2.column1

etc...

I could give you an exact answer if you supplied your full schema and foreign and primary keys for the tables.

Comment: So you're saying the error isn't in my INSERT INTO query but in the union query? In all honesty, I'm not quire sure what you mean by full schema (kinda a noob here with access &SQL) but essentially, we get records written into our access table from a 3rd party program. These records go like "question answer rank, question2 answer2 rank2 and so forth. We exceeded the 255 field limit so we broke down the question, answer, rank, comments, into separate table. And now we need to break the record down to one question with corresponding answer, rank & comment as one record, into a secondary table.

Comment: (s)he's saying you didn't join the QR table to anything, so every record in QR is being returned for EACH record in SSIAns, SSIRank and SSIComment. -- It's certianly not an infinite loop, but you could be looking at hundreds of millions of rows. You need to link the QR table to another table or constrain it somehow. 
FROM SSIAns, SSIRank,SSIComment, QR

WHERE 
SSIRank.Rank_50 = "2_Address_Within_3_Days" AND 
SSIAns.Form_Record_Number=SSIRank.Form_Record_Number 
AND SSIRank.Form_Record_Number =SSIComment.Form_Record_Number

Comment: If adding the `JOIN` doesn't help (use the `ON` clause instead of `WHERE` in Access-SQL), look through the union query for Nulls. In my experience, that's usually my issue: not properly handling Nulls. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243855(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: I think I understand what you both are saying. I added the line "AND QR.ID=1" to the WHERE , but I still seem to be running the error.

Comment: What are the columns that are relatable between your QR table and your other tables you have in your query?

For example: If QR has the column "ID" does any of the other tables have something along the lines of "QuestionID" or "QRID"? If so then in the where clause you need to put it as QR.ID = Table.QRID

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, does the JOIN or INNERJOIN allow you to split up the same record into several different records?

Comment: I'm going to guess we are going about these tables wrong, but the QR table is literally one record of just descriptive text that pertains to each question. This table, is static, will not change, and is just a reference I suppose, that we need to add to each record in the new table we want to insert into.

Comment: If you are looking to do that then just add hard code into the query itself. Instead of doing "SELECT QR.question" just write "SELECT 'question goes here' as Question" This will prevent an unnecessary table addition and may solve your issue. Access might just not like having a table appended to a query that isnt joined to anything and perceives it as too complex.

Answer (score 1):

One method could be to split the operation into two steps.

First, write the output of the union query to a (temp) table. If you use "Create Table" it's quite simple.

Second, use that table as source for an append query, actually your current "insert into" statement where you use replace *SSIQuery* with the table name.